# Bounce Objects Inside other Object

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to make objects bounce around a constraint.  My first thought was to place the objects inside a sphere and have them bounce around; however, the objects just fall through.  Even though I use the Physics to make the Sphere Rigid.

The effect I am trying to do is like Bingo Balls bouncing inside the globe before being extracted.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you,

Comment: You have to **FLIP NORMALS** to keep the objects inside that sphere ... checked now and working buddy so try.

Comment: You also could look at this .blend mate: (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5317/)

Comment: Jan,  Thank you for your input.  Unfortunately, i am unable to get it to work.  The objects just fall through the sphere.  I downloaded your example and appended the IcoSphere into my project and its a "no-go".  When I add **Rigid Body** the objects fly out of the sphere.  With **Collision** the objects just drop through.  I'm probably missing something simple.  Thanks again!

Comment: I just opened up a new Blender session, added an Ico sphere (5 subdivisions) and scaled it by 6. Then switched to edit mode and Flipped normals. The I added another ico sphere and added a rigid body as Active from the tool bar and selected the initial large inverted sphere and set it as rigid body Passive. Ran the animation and the light sphere falls down and rolls around in the big sphere with falling out. Note: I am using the quick physics from the tool bar, so it might have some differences from the defaults if you use the actual physics tab.

Comment: Probably also possible, I made that sphere with **flipped normals** a _Collision_ object which also works well as could be seen using my .blend file. So Mike, You could append my sphere, than add your balls into it and make them **RigidBody** (with Edges Bending = 10+! and Goal _turnded OFF_) and also **Collision**, No they will interact with each other and also NOT drop thru the "normals-flipped sphere" ... thats all I done in my scene.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with rigid body objects, you could try and set the container object *Collisions > Shape* to *Mesh*, inside the *RigidBody* properties.